# The scheduling order of Promise.then promises when grouped in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I encountered a very interesting problem recently. The background is that I want to fire a bunch of http requests concurrently, and capture the result of each response in an array. Also, when all promises of requests are resolved, .
I tried two ways to implement it but sometimes got different results.

Look at the following code snippets (`httpHelper.get` just returns a BlueBird promise).
**Solution A:**

```
function solutionA() {
  var requestOptions = [...]; // an array of request options
  var promises = [];
  var results = [];
  _.forEach(requestOptions, function(requestOption){
     var promise = httpHelper.get(requestOption).then(function singleThenCallBack(response){
            //Using this solution, sometimes this code won't execute from some response, I guess it's because the Promise.all.then gets executed before this then.
            results.push(response.body.result);
     });
     promises.push(promise);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function allThenCallBack(){
    return results;
  });
}
```

**Solution B**:

```
function solutionB() {
  var requestOptions = [...]; // an array of request options
  var promises = [];
  var results = [];
  _.forEach(requestOptions, function singleThenCallBack(requestOption){
     var promise = httpHelper.get(requestOption);
     promises.push(promise);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function allThenCallBack(responses){
    _.forEach(responses, function(response){
       results.push(response.body.result);
    });
    return results;
  });
}
```

So the problem of using Solution A is that, sometimes the `singleThenCallBack` function won't be called on some response, so the `results` doesn't contain every result I should get. 
Solution B always ensure that all results are push into array `results`. I guess the cause is the timing how the `then` for `Promise` and `Promise.all` is scheduled.
My question is that in Solution A, shouldn't the `promises` be the promises of the `Promise.then`s, which would ensure `singleThenCallBack` function for all responses should be called before `allThenCallBack` function is reached?

Hope someone could explain the reason of this behaviour to me. Thanks!

**Edit**:
So I tried to run some code to prove the promise chaining with following code:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var promises = [];

var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(1);
    }, 5000);
});

var thenPromise1 = promise1.then(function(value){
    console.log("********* resolved promise1 *********: " + value);
    console.log(promise1);
    return 0.1;
}, console.log("*****This means then function is called synchronously."));

promises.push(thenPromise1);

thenPromise1.then(function(value){
    console.log("********* resolved thenPromise1 *********: " + value);
    console.log(thenPromise1);
});

var allPromise = Promise.all(promises);

allPromise.then(function(value){
    console.log("********* resolved allPromise *********: " + value);
    console.log(allPromise);
});

console.log("********* promise1 *********");
console.log(promise1);
console.log("********* thenPromise1 *********");
console.log(thenPromise1);
console.log("********* allPromise *********");
console.log(allPromise);

console.log("***********code end*************");
```

And the output is:

```
*****This means then function is called synchronously.
********* promise1 *********
{ _bitField: 1,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: 
   { '2': 0,
     '3': 
      { _promise: [Object],
        _values: [Object],
        _length: 1,
        _totalResolved: 0 },
     _bitField: 2,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: 
      { _bitField: 0,
        _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
        _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
        _promise0: undefined,
        _receiver0: undefined,
        _trace: [Object] },
     _receiver0: undefined,
     _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } },
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } }
********* thenPromise1 *********
{ '2': 0,
  '3': 
   { _promise: 
      { _bitField: 134217729,
        _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
        _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
        _promise0: [Object],
        _receiver0: undefined },
     _values: [ [Circular] ],
     _length: 1,
     _totalResolved: 0 },
  _bitField: 2,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: 
   { _bitField: 0,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: undefined,
     _receiver0: undefined,
     _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } },
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } }
********* allPromise *********
{ _bitField: 134217729,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: 
   { _bitField: 0,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: undefined,
     _receiver0: undefined,
     _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } },
  _receiver0: undefined }
***********code end*************
********* resolved promise1 *********: 1
{ _bitField: 33554433,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: 1,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } }
********* resolved thenPromise1 *********: 0.1
{ '2': 0,
  '3': 
   { _promise: 
      { _bitField: 134217729,
        _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
        _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
        _promise0: [Object],
        _receiver0: undefined },
     _values: [ [Circular] ],
     _length: 1,
     _totalResolved: 0 },
  _bitField: 33554434,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: 0.1,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _trace: { [Error] _parent: undefined, _promisesCreated: 0, _length: 1 } }
********* resolved allPromise *********: 0.1
{ _bitField: 167772161,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: [ 0.1 ],
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

In the output, the `thenPromise1` object has the `_promise0`, which is the promise created by `thenPromise1.then(...)`. And the promise object after `'3'` is the promise that created by `Promise.all(...)`, which means this promise is always chained after the `thenPromise1`.
So I think the question was invalid and something was wrong in other parts.

Comment: Where you check the count of `results` in your code?

Comment: Not showed in here, it's the caller of the SolutionA/B function.

Comment: You really should use `map` instead of `forEach`+`push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not explain the problem of the OP but I does not fit into a comment.

That does not make sense. Both `solutionA` or `solutionB` should have the same result. Either all Promises are successfully resolved, and then `results.length` has to be equal to `requestOptions.length` or one or more of the `httpHelper.get(requestOption)` fail, and then also the `Promise.all(promises)` will be rejected and no `result` will be returned. So I'm pretty sure that the problem is anywhere else.

Beside that as you use bluebird you can write your code in a much clearer way (assuming that you use `const Promise = require('bluebird')`:

```
function solution() {
  var requestOptions = [...]; // an array of request options

  return Promise.all(requestOptions)  // pass all request options
    .map(function(requestOption) {  // for each option create a request and return its promise
        return httpHelper.get(requestOption);
    }) 
    .map(function(response) { // for each response return the response.body.result
       return response.body.result;
    }); // now the promise resolves to an array containing the just the response.body.result
}

solutionA()
.then(function( result ) {
   console.dir(result);
});
```

With ES6 you could use Arrow functions write it that way:

```
function solution() {
  var requestOptions = [...]; // an array of request options

  return Promise.all(requestOptions)  // pass all request options
    .map( requestOption => httpHelper.get(requestOption) )
    .map( response => response.body.result );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly how I think it should work, which makes me super confusing when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `.then()` handlers on your initial promise will execute BEFORE the `Promise.all()` `.then()` handler will execute.  This is because the original promises are not done and resolved until the `.then()` handler has been called (as it could return a chained promise that the higher level promise would have to wait for before it resolves).  But, those original `.then()` handlers will not execute in a predictable order because all your operations are running in parallel which means your `results` array in solutionA is not in order.

I would suggest that you just change the result of the original promise like this:

```
  _.forEach(requestOptions, function(requestOption){
     var promise = httpHelper.get(requestOption).then(function singleThenCallBack(response){
         // change resolved value to be the body.result
         return response.body.result;
     });
     promises.push(promise);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
```

---

But, if you're using Bluebird, you may as well use `Promise.map()` which combines the iteration with the `Promise.all()`.

```
return Promise.map(requestOptions, function(item) {
    return httpHelper.get(item).then(function(response) {
        return response.body.result;
    });
});
```

Comment: @david-z - Hey David.  Are you here?  A couple of us posted answers and we haven't heard anything back from you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I believe the problem is happening here. Is there any helpful documentation explaining how that work internally? I didn't find any.

Comment: @DavidZ. - What do you mean "problem happening here"?  And, what documentation are you looking for?

Comment: the problem that solutionA that doesn't include all the results. The order of the results actually don't matter.

Comment: @DavidZ. - What do you mean it doesn't contain all the results?  Is the results array too short or some of the positions in the results array are empty or undefined?  We need much more specific details from your own debugging in order to help you.  Unless `httpHelper().get()` has bugs, all the results should be there if you are using the returned promise correctly.  Maybe you need to show more of your code including `httpHelper()` and how you are using the the resulting promise?